# disable a form submit button until a textarea has been populated?

Tags: javascript

can someone please help because i have tried various javascripts to get my form submit button to stay disabled until a user enters text into the textarea but nothings working.

i want the submit button to be disabled until a user enters some text. any suggestions please?

```
  <form action="includes/welcomebio.php" method="post" id="form12" class="form12">          
 <textarea id="bio" textarea name="bio" data-id="bio" placeholder="Hi, my name is Peter. I'm 22 years old from North Wales." onKeyUp="checkWordCount();" data-required="true"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($profile['bio']); ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="welcome-submit" name="submit" value="Next ->" id="submit"/>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function disable() 
{ 
if(document.textarea.bio.value=="") 
{ 
document.textarea.submit.disabled=true; 
} 
else 
{ 
document.textarea.submit.disabled=false;    
} 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many things wrong with your code:

1. Try not to use inline javascript
2. your textarea `onKeyUp` calls a function that does not exist
3. you are trying to set the disabled state of the wrong element (you actually have invalid javascript)
4. you have some invalid html too

This is what you want:

HTML

```
<form action="includes/welcomebio.php" method="post" id="form12" class="form12">
    <textarea id="bio" name="bio" data-id="bio" data-required="true" placeholder="Hi, my name is Peter. I'm 22 years old from North Wales.">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($profile['bio']); ?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="welcome-submit" name="submit" value="Next ->" id="submit" />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("bio").onkeyup = checkWordCount;
    checkWordCount();
};

function checkWordCount() {
    if (document.getElementById("bio").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/PrskS/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to disable the textarea instead of the submit button. Your code isn't valid JavaScript.
Keep the submit button disabled initially and enable it only when the textarea has something in it.  Also, since you're using a placeholder for the textarea, your textarea would never be empty, so a check for

```
document.getElementById("bio").value = ""
```

would always return false unless the user changes it.

Comment: how would i change it then please to disable the submit button?

Comment: Add the disabled attribute to the submit button. `<input type="submit" class="welcome-submit" name="submit" value="Next ->" id="submit" disabled/>`

Comment: but then this just disables it completely, even when i type in the textarea field the button stays disabled

Comment: In the onkeyup event handler, check if the textarea's value != "" and enable the button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <body onload="disable()">
 <form action="includes/welcomebio.php" method="post" id="form12" class="form12">          
 <textarea id="bio" textarea name="bio" data-id="bio" placeholder="Hi, my name is Peter. I'm 22 years old from North Wales." onKeyUp="disable();checkWordCount();" data-required="true"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="welcome-submit" name="submit" value="Next ->" id="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function disable() 
{ 
    if(document.getElementById("bio").value=="") 
    { 
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;    
    } 
} 
</script>
```